# Java Android: How to give media player a string value to a resource

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have a function where i run an audio

```
public void PlaySound(String FileName){
     MediaPlr = MediaPlayer.create(Context, R.raw.s1);
     MediaPlr.start();
}
```

The problem is `R.raw.s1`, i want to replace `s1` with `FileName`, but it doesn't take a String.
What can i do???

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is stored in the `res/raw/` directory, you can retrieve its identifier through the following code:

```
public void PlaySound(String fileName){
    int sound_id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "raw",
                                                 context.getPackageName());
    if(sound_id != 0) {
      mediaPlr = MediaPlayer.create(context, sound_id);
      mediaPlr.start();
    }
}
```

I would also prefer to start variable names with small letters, rather than capital. This helps to distinguish from the static class.

You can also create a map to store the ID for further reuse instead of retrieving the identifier each time.

Comment: now i want to choose a file inside a folder inside the raw folder, as raw/sound/s1

Comment: Android recommend to keep the hierarchy flat for this kind of folders. Better use a prefix instead like `raw/sounds_s1.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.You can specify your string file path in [`mediaPlayer.setDataSource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.lang.String%29)

```
if(mMediaPlayer == null)
    mMediaPlayer    =   new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.reset();
try {
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(YourAudioFileLocation);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: i tried : MediaPlr.setDataSource("raw/sound/win.mp3"); but no sound !! , is this true ?!or not ?